# Find specific numbers of capitalized words next to each other

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

Let's say I have a .txt file:

```
Aaa
Aaa Bbb
Aaa Bbb Ccc
```

I want to find the row that has one capitalized word, two capitalized words, and three capitalized words. So one grep to find Aaa, one grep to find Aaa Bbb, and one grep to find Aab Bbb Ccc. This have to be done so the grep that finds Aaa Bbc doesnt find the one with Aaa Bbb Ccc (because the same words are in it). SO:

```
1 grep 
**Aaa**

2 grep
**Aaa Bbb**

3 grep
**Aaa Bbb Ccc**
```

This means that the first grep cannot find the Aaa in the second and third and so on. They have to work only if one, two or three letters start with a uppercase.

Kind regards
Anders

Comment: This sounds like homework 

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The last part contradicts what's shown in the example.

Comment: `grep -Pwo '^([^a-z]*[A-Z]\w*\b){1}[^A-Z]*$' text.txt | grep -Ev '[A-Z]{3,}'` was the best I could, at least with grep don't think its possible to do with one grep

Comment: I need to find names and count them. So I need to find how many `John`, `John Johnsen` and `John Johnson Johny` there are for instance.

Comment: @bac0n your example does the job for the first John (and excludes the John Johnsen and John Johnson Johny which is nice!). Now I just need to find out the same for the other twos

Comment: But by editing the {1} to {2} and {3} as well does the job! Thank you :-)

Comment: @bac0n Do you know how to do it in rows? Like finding this (because it has tre rows staring with a capital letter):

Aaa (newline) Bbb (newline) Ccc

Comment: If I understand you right you could get the count from the second `grep -Evc '[A-Z]{3,}'`